# Any ideas how to convert array into FOR Loop?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The code below works great as is:

```
dashboard1.Text = charArray(0)
dashboard2.Text = charArray(1)
dashboard3.Text = charArray(2)
dashboard4.Text = charArray(3)
dashboard5.Text = charArray(4)
dashboard6.Text = charArray(5)
dashboard7.Text = ""
dashboard8.Text = ""
dashboard9.Text = ""
dashboard10.Text = ""
If dashboardl >= 7 Then
    dashboard7.Text = charArray(6)
End If
If dashboardl >= 8 Then
    dashboard8.Text = charArray(7)
End If

If dashboardl >= 9 Then
    dashboard9.Text = charArray(8)
End If
If dashboardl >= 10 Then
    dashboard10.Text = charArray(9)
End If
```

However, I would like to convert them to FOR Loop as in example below but I am getting errors.

```
For i = 1 To (dashboardl)
        ("dashboard" & CStr(i)) = charArray(i - 1)
Next i
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Creating Control Arrays in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this...

```
    For i = 1 To dashboardl
        Dim txtBox As TextBox = FindControl("dashboard" & i)
        txtBox.Text = charArray(i - 1)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I missed the point. Still not on a real computer, but try this...

```
For i = 1 To dashboardl
    Me.Controls("dashboard" & CStr(i)).Text = charArray(i - 1)
Next i
```

Comment: Brian, thanks guys for your assistance. I am getting an error that Text is not a member of System.Web.UI.Control. I am using RadioButtonList on the html form.

Will something like formName.SelectedValue = charArray(i - 1)
 work?